# elasticsearch groovy No such property: ctx for class

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

This my first time using script in elasticsearch and I got following issue:

```
curl -XPOST 10.29.97.129:9200/.marvel-es-1-*/_search -d '{
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "filter": [
                {
                  "range": {
                    "timestamp": {
                      "gte": "now-2m",
                      "lte": "now"
                    }
                  }
                },
                {
                  "terms": {
                    "cluster_state.status": ["green", "yellow", "red"]
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "_source": [
            "cluster_state.status"
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "timestamp": {
                "order": "desc"
              }
            }
          ],
          "size": 1,
          "aggs": {
            "minutes": {
              "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "interval": "5s"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "status": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "cluster_state.status",
                    "size": 3
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "script_fields" : {
            "aggregationstest" : {
              "script": "return ctx.payload"
            }
          }   
 }'
```

> {"took":5751,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":29,"successful":12,"failed":1,"failures":[{"shard":0,"index":".marvel-es-1-2016.07.04","node":"ZjBZ7bt2QAmAvuDe-Uhf-A","reason":{"type":"script_exception","reason":"failed
>   to run inline script [return ctx.payload] using lang
>   [groovy]","caused_by":{"type":"missing_property_exception","reason":"No
>   such property: ctx for class:
>   390476cf551361b607cbac07bb49053c5bcd3e62"}}}]},"hits":{"total":10,"max_score":null,"hits":[]},"aggregations":{"minutes":{"buckets":[{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:10.000Z","key":1467594130000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:15.000Z","key":1467594135000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:20.000Z","key":1467594140000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:25.000Z","key":1467594145000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:30.000Z","key":1467594150000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:35.000Z","key":1467594155000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:40.000Z","key":1467594160000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:45.000Z","key":1467594165000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:50.000Z","key":1467594170000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:02:55.000Z","key":1467594175000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:00.000Z","key":1467594180000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:05.000Z","key":1467594185000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:10.000Z","key":1467594190000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:15.000Z","key":1467594195000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:20.000Z","key":1467594200000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:25.000Z","key":1467594205000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:30.000Z","key":1467594210000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:35.000Z","key":1467594215000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:40.000Z","key":1467594220000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:45.000Z","key":1467594225000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:50.000Z","key":1467594230000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:03:55.000Z","key":1467594235000,"doc_count":0,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[]}},{"key_as_string":"2016-07-04T01:04:00.000Z","key":1467594240000,"doc_count":1,"status":{"doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,"sum_other_doc_count":0,"buckets":[{"key":"green","doc_count":1}]}}]}}}

As I known, `ctx` is `groovy` default `context`, any one could give me some hints??